# How to calculate the square of (x + x2 + x4 + x5+x8) using FFT in PHP?

Tags: php, fft

It's from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560523/onlogn-algorithm-find-three-evenly-spaced-ones-within-binary-string/1585303#1585303),which is said to be a `nlgn` algorithm.

Comment: This may be a useful starting point: http://www.zend.com//code/codex.php?ozid=259&single=1

Comment: You might also find this useful for theory: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Fast_convolution_algorithms

Comment: Are you trying to solve the linked problem in PHP, trying to calculate the square of the given polynomial, or are you trying to calculate the asymptotic complexity of the naive solution?