# Efficient Longest arithmetic progression for a set of linear Points

Tags: c++, python, algorithm, math, geometry

Longest arithmetic progression of a set of numbers {ab<sub>1</sub>,ab<sub>2</sub>,ab<sub>3</sub> .... ab<sub>n</sub>} is defined as a subset {bb<sub>1</sub>,bb<sub>2</sub>,bb<sub>3</sub> .... bb<sub>n</sub>} such that b<sub>i+1</sub> - b<sub>i</sub> is constant.

I would like to extend this problems to a set of two dimensional points lying on a straight line.
Lets define Dist(P<sub>1</sub>,P<sub>2</sub>) is the distance between two Points P<sub>1</sub>(X<sub>1</sub>,Y<sub>1</sub>) and P<sub>2</sub>(X<sub>2</sub>,Y<sub>2</sub>) on a line as

Dist(P<sub>1</sub>,P<sub>2</sub>) = Dist((X<sub>1</sub>,Y<sub>1</sub>),(X<sub>2</sub>,Y<sub>2</sub>)) = (X<sub>2</sub> - X<sub>1</sub>)<sup>2</sup> + (Y<sub>2</sub> - Y<sub>1</sub>))<sup>2</sup>

Now For a given set of points I need to find the largest Arithmetic Progression such that  Dist(P<sub>i</sub>,P<sub>i+1</sub>) is constant, assuming they all lie on the same line (m & C are constant).

I researched a bit but could not figure out an algorithm which is better than O(n<sup>2</sup>).

In fact  currently the way I am doing is I am maintaining a Dictionary say

```
DistDict=dict()
```

and say Points are defined in a List as

```
Points = [(X1,Y1),(X2,Y2),....]
```

then this is what I am doing

```
for i,pi in enumerate(Points):
    for pj in Points[i+1:]:
         DistDict.setdefault(dist(pi,pj),set([])).add((pi,pj))
```

so all I have ended up with a dictionary of points which are of equal distance. So the only thing I have to do is to scan through to find out the longest `set`.

I am just wondering that this ought to have a better solution, but somehow I can't figure out one. I have also seen couple of similar older SO posts but none I can find to give something that is more efficient than O(n<sup>2</sup>). Is this somehow an NP Hard problem that we can never have something better or if not what approach could be take.
Please note I came across a post which claims about an efficient  [divide and conquer algorithm](http://www.cs.uiuc.edu/~jeffe/pubs/pdf/arith.pdf) but couldn't make any head or tail out of it.

Any help in this regard?

Note*** I am tagging this Python because I understand Python better than maybe Matlab or Ruby. C/C++/Java is also fine as I am somewhat proficient in these too :-)

Comment: if you have O(n^p) algorithm where p is constant, then this problem is not NP-hard assuming that P != NP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum things up: As @TonyK pointed out, if you assume that the points lie on a straight line, you can reduce it to the one-dimensional case that was [discussed extensively here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560523/onlogn-algorithm-find-three-evenly-spaced-ones-within-binary-string) already. The solution uses Fast Fourier Transforms as mentioned by @YochaiTimmer.

Additional note: The problem is almost certainly not NP-hard as it has an efficient O(n log n) solution, so that would imply P=NP.

Comment: Thanks. I need some time to go through it and see if I can extend the concept beyond three evenly spaced points.

Comment: It is `O(n log n)` where `n` is the distance between the extreme points (assuming all distances are integers). But it is `O(n^2)` in the number of points.

Comment: Just wondering if the said algorithm can be extended beyond 3 points. I am still brainstorming on that. If its O(n^2) for the number of points, do we get any advantage of using it, assuming the above algorithm I mentioned is actually O(n^2) where n is the number of points in the linear space.

Answer (score 1):

You could study the **[Fast Fourier Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform)** methods [for multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Fourier_transform_methods).O(N log N)

You might be able to do something similar with your problem.

Comment: Thanks. May take some time to go through it. I will get back once I am done reading it.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your definition of distance is wrong. You have to take the square root. Secondly, if you know that all the points lie on a straight line, you can simply ignore the y-coordinates (unless the line is vertical) or the x-coordinates (unless the line is horizontal). Then it reduces to the problem in your first paragraph.

Comment: I know the definition of distance is wrong. I just don't want to add an overhead of finding the square root which won't add any value but just to conform with the definition. Secondly I can strip of the y-coordinate but the points may line along X or Y axis. Also I just can't remember the term they call for square of a distance so just calling it distance for the sake.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more elaborate with my previous comment. Actually this is part of a larger problem, where there are some points on a plane that I have to group in a way that they are all linear and then I have to figure this out. Currently both of these I am doing in one iteration.