# Find if 2b=a+c in a given array of n elements in O(n*log n)?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity

Can someone provide an O(n*log n)  algorithm that accepts an array of length n which has elements in the range 
 {1,2,3....n} as input and checks whether the array contains 2b = a+c ? I know how to do it in O(n * n) but I need to optimise it to O(n* log n).

Comment: What are a, b and c? elements in the set?

Comment: Yes ,the elements in the input set which is a subset of {1,2,3,4....n}

Comment: What have you tried so far? Share your findings! Show us some code!

Comment: I got O(n * n) algorithm but I need it in O(n* log n) time.

Comment: I think you want the algorithm stack exchange, unless you plan on putting this into some sort of specific coding language.

Comment: What gives you the impression that there is a O(n* log n) solution? Is this HOMEWORK ?

Comment: O(1) is a subset of `O(n*log n)`.

Comment: @greybeard: I agree. Do you have an O(1) algorithm to solve this? Would be a very suitable answer to the question.

Comment: Really an interesting problem. I can't figure out a solution, but a found it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560523/onlogn-algorithm-find-three-evenly-spaced-ones-within-binary-string/1579165#1579165

Comment: Thanks @liliscent for giving the hint ,by the way this was a question which appeared in my exam yesterday for which the syllabus was FFT,Divide and conquer.I wasn't able to figure it out as I was thinking it to solve it in Divide and conquer way.I didn't thought it would involve FFT.Now I will proceed with the link given.

Comment: If you don't exclude a=b=c, I guess there is a (low) limit to n above which such a triple *always* exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please don't laugh at such questions if you don't know the answer.I figured out the answer myself by the link posted in the comments.
Source:[O(nlogn) Algorithm - Find three evenly spaced ones within binary string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560523/onlogn-algorithm-find-three-evenly-spaced-ones-within-binary-string/1579165#1579165)

The solution is,
Let L = [1, 2, 4, 5, 8].

1. The  problem is now to find an arithmetic progression of length 3 in L, i.e. to find distinct a, b, c in L such that b-a = c-b, or equivalently a+c=2b. For the example above, we want to find the progression (2, 5, 8).

Make a polynomial p with terms xk for each k in L. For the example above, we make the polynomial p(x) = (x + x2 + x4 + x5+x8). This step is O(n).

Find the polynomial q = p2, using the Fast Fourier Transform. For the example above, we get the polynomial q(x) = x16 + 2x13 + 2x12 + 3x10 + 4x9 + x8 + 2x7 + 4x6 + 2x5 + x4 + 2x3 + x2. This step is O(n log n).

Ignore all terms except those corresponding to x2k for some k in L. For the example above, we get the terms x16, 3x10, x8, x4, x2. This step is O(n), if you choose to do it at all.

Here's the crucial point: the coefficient of any x2b for b in L is precisely the number of pairs (a,c) in L such that a+c=2b. [CLRS, Ex. 30.1-7] One such pair is (b,b) always (so the coefficient is at least 1), but if there exists any other pair (a,c), then the coefficient is at least 3, from (a,c) and (c,a). For the example above, we have the coefficient of x10 to be 3 precisely because of the AP (2,5,8). (These coefficients x2b will always be odd numbers, for the reasons above. And all other coefficients in q will always be even.)

So the total time complexity won't cross O(n* logn).

Thankyou.

Comment: So this question is duplicated?