# How to find if 3 numbers in a set of size N exactly sum up to M

Tags: c++, algorithm

I want to know how I can implement a better solution than O(N^3). Its similar to the knapsack and subset problems. In my question N<=8000, so i started computing sums of pairs of numbers and stored them in an array. Then I would binary search in the sorted set for each (M-sum[i]) value but the problem arises how will I keep track of the indices which summed up to sum[i]. I know I could declare extra space but my Sums array already has a size of 64 million, and hence I couldn't complete my O(N^2) solution. Please advice if I can do some optimization or if I need some totally different technique.

Comment: Seen this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: edit: I'll take a stab, just for fun -- how about sort the set first. Then a nested for(i = 0..n) for(j == i+1..n), and then search for the third value from j+1..n. So no extra storage needed, and still n^2 log n.

Comment: i need to keep track of which indices summed up to which sums which does require space additional to the 8000*8000 already declared

Comment: @sanchit.h You *need* additional space to track which numbers were used. You only need to store one of them, from which you can deduce the other.

Comment: oh, maybe I misunderstood. Are you looking for a particular M, or a report for all M's?

Comment: @sanchit.h: why are you storing the (up to) N^2 sums-of-two? You could iterate through them, and as you generate each one search into the sorted original set of N to see whether it contains M - sum_of_two. That's around a billion repeats of the inner loop of the binary search, which isn't trivial but is feasible.

Comment: @david:i supply the 'M' value
@Steve: oh! that would solve my memory problem now O(N^2 * logn)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could benefit from some generic tricks to improve the performance of your algorithm.

1) Don't store what you use only once

It is a common error to store more than you really need. Whenever your memory requirement seem to blow up the first question to ask yourself is *Do I really need to store that stuff ?* Here it turns out that you do not (as Steve explained in comments), compute the sum of two numbers (in a triangular fashion to avoid repeating yourself) and then check for the presence of the third one.

> We drop the O(N**2) memory complexity! Now expected memory is O(N).

2) Know your data structures, and in particular: the hash table

*Perfect* hash tables are rarely (if ever) implemented, but it is (in theory) possible to craft hash tables with O(1) insertion, check and deletion characteristics, and in practice you do approach those complexities (tough it generally comes at the cost of a high constant factor that will make you prefer so-called *suboptimal* approaches).

Therefore, unless you need ordering (for some reason), membership is better tested through a hash table in general.

> We drop the 'log N' term in the speed complexity.

With those two recommendations you easily get what you were asking for:

1. Build a simple hash table: the number is the key, the index the satellite data associated
2. Iterate in triangle fashion over your data set: `for i in [0..N-1]; for j in [i+1..N-1]`
3. At each iteration, check if `K = M - set[i] - set[j]` is in the hash table, if it is, extract `k = table[K]` and *if `k != i` and `k != j`* store the triple `(i,j,k)` in your result.

If a single result is sufficient, you can stop iterating as soon as you get the first result, otherwise you just store all the triples.

Comment: What happens when k = i or k = j?

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple O(n^2) solution to this that uses only O(1)* memory if you only want to find the 3 numbers (O(n) memory if you want the indices of the numbers and the set is not already sorted).

First, sort the set.

Then for each element in the set, see if there are two (other) numbers that sum to it. This is a common interview question and can be done in O(n) on a sorted set.

The idea is that you start a pointer at the beginning and one at the end, if your current sum is not the target, if it is greater than the target, decrement the end pointer, else increment the start pointer.

So for each of the n numbers we do an O(n) search and we get an O(n^2) algorithm.

---

*Note that this requires a sort that uses O(1) memory. Hell, since the sort need only be O(n^2) you could use bubble sort. Heapsort is O(n log n) and uses O(1) memory.

Answer (score 1):

Create a "bitset" of all the numbers which makes it constant time to check if a number is there. That is a start.

The solution will then be at most O(N^2) to make all combinations of 2 numbers.

The only tricky bit here is when the solution contains a repeat, but it doesn't really matter, you can discard repeats unless it is the same number 3 times because you will hit the "repeat" case when you pair up the 2 identical numbers and see if the unique one is present.

The 3 times one is simply a matter of checking if M is divisible by 3 and whether M/3 appears 3 times as you create the bitset.

This solution does require creating extra storage, up to MAX/8 where MAX is the highest number in your set. You could use a hash table though if this number exceeds a certain point: still O(1) lookup.

Comment: Does "set" imply no repeats? (math lingo vs class lingo...)

Comment: In C++ std::set implies elements are unique. Not sure if that is necessarily implied in the problem though.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work for me...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm> 
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
  set<long long> keys;

  // By default this set is sorted
  set<short> N;
  N.insert(4);
  N.insert(8);
  N.insert(19);
  N.insert(5);
  N.insert(12);
  N.insert(35);
  N.insert(6);
  N.insert(1);

  typedef set<short>::iterator iterator;

  const short M = 18;

  for(iterator i(N.begin()); i != N.end() && *i < M; ++i)
  {
    short d1 = M - *i; // subtract the value at this location
    // if there is more to "consume"
    if (d1 > 0)
    {
      // ignore below i as we will have already scanned it...
      for(iterator j(i); j != N.end() && *j < M; ++j)
      {
        short d2 = d1 - *j; // again "consume" as much as we can
        // now the remainder must eixst in our set N
        if (N.find(d2) != N.end())
        {
          // means that the three numbers we've found, *i (from first loop), *j (from second loop) and d2 exist in our set of N
          // now to generate the unique combination, we need to generate some form of key for our keys set
          // here we take advantage of the fact that all the numbers fit into a short, we can construct such a key with a long long (8 bytes)

          // the 8 byte key is made up of 2 bytes for i, 2 bytes for j and 2 bytes for d2
          // and is formed in sorted order

          long long key = *i; // first index is easy
          // second index slightly trickier, if it's less than j, then this short must be "after" i
          if (*i < *j)
            key = (key << 16) | *j; 
          else
            key |= (static_cast<int>(*j) << 16); // else it's before i

          // now the key is either: i | j, or j | i (where i & j are two bytes each, and the key is currently 4 bytes)

          // third index is a bugger, we have to scan the key in two byte chunks to insert our third short
          if ((key & 0xFFFF) < d2)
            key = (key << 16) | d2;  // simple, it's the largest of the three
          else if (((key >> 16) & 0xFFFF) < d2)
            key = (((key << 16) | (key & 0xFFFF)) & 0xFFFF0000FFFFLL) | (d2 << 16); // its less than j but greater i
          else
            key |= (static_cast<long long>(d2) << 32); // it's less than i

          // Now if this unique key already exists in the hash, this won't insert an entry for it
          keys.insert(key);
        }
        // else don't care...
      }
    }
  }
  // tells us how many unique combinations there are  
  cout << "size: " << keys.size() << endl;
  // prints out the 6 bytes for representing the three numbers
  for(set<long long>::iterator it (keys.begin()), end(keys.end()); it != end; ++it)
     cout << hex << *it << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Okay, here is attempt two: this generates the output:

```
start: 19
size: 4
10005000c
400060008
500050008
600060006
```

As you can see from there, the first "key" is the three shorts (in hex), 0x0001, 0x0005, 0x000C (which is 1, 5, 12 = 18), etc.

Okay, cleaned up the code some more, realised that the reverse iteration is pointless..

My Big O notation is not the best (never studied computer science), however I think the above is something like, `O(N)` for outer and `O(NlogN)` for inner, reason for `log N` is that `std::set::find()` is logarithmic - however if you replace this with a hashed set, the inner loop could be as good as `O(N)` - please someone correct me if this is crap...

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your solution is doing, but it does not answer the question.

Comment: @tyree731, op wants three numbers that sum up to M, that's exactly what this is finding... for example in the above case, there are ~6.8 million unique combinations of numbers in the set N which sums up to 9323 - or have I missed something?

Comment: i have given a set of numbers from which to find those 3 numbers. btw how much memory would 128 million ints occupy? if less than 64 MB then I'm done my soln is O(N^2 + NlogN)

Comment: change N to 10 and M to 13 (for example), this generates 13 unique combinations that sum up to 13 (1 2 10, 1 3 9 etc.) - this is what you are after right?

Comment: ahh - sorry, read your question again, what's in the set is unknown.. back to the drawing board, I just read that the set has all the numbers up to N rather than it's just a set of unique numbers and the set size is N!

Comment: no for example i give nos 4 8 19 35 6 and i ask if any three of these sum up to 18. trivial soln is O(N^3) and i was searching for smthg better thanks anyway

Comment: @sanchit.h, is there an upper bound on the number that could occur in the set, i.e. can you take advantage of the fact that the number could fit into a short? If so, it's trivial to change my solution

Comment: i dont think any no. in N will be more than 32000(int) but i don't know about set.h and shorts never used'em before

Comment: @sanchit.h, okay, code updated. If you are not familiar with structures like `std::set`, you should may be read up on it...

Answer (score 0):

I combined the suggestions by @Matthieu M. and @Chris Hopman, and (after much trial and error) I came up with this algorithm that should be O(n log n + log (n-k)! + k) in time and O(log(n-k)) in space (the stack). That [should be](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Orders_of_common_functions) O(n log n) overall. It's in Python, but it doesn't use any Python-specific features.

```
import bisect

def binsearch(r, q, i, j): # O(log (j-i))
    return bisect.bisect_left(q, r, i, j)

def binfind(q, m, i, j):    
    while i + 1 < j:
        r = m - (q[i] + q[j])
        if r < q[i]:
            j -= 1
        elif r > q[j]:
            i += 1
        else:
            k = binsearch(r, q, i + 1, j - 1)  # O(log (j-i))
            if not (i < k < j):
                return None
            elif q[k] == r:
                return (i, k, j)
            else:
                return (
                    binfind(q, m, i + 1, j)
                    or
                    binfind(q, m, i, j - 1)
                    )

def find_sumof3(q, m):
    return binfind(sorted(q), m, 0, len(q) - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not trying to boast about my programming skills or add redundant stuff here.
Just wanted to provide beginners with an implementation in C++.
Implementation based on the pseudocode provided by Charles Ma at [Given an array of numbers, find out if 3 of them add up to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283231/given-an-array-of-numbers-find-out-if-3-of-them-add-up-to-0/15451612#15451612).
I hope the comments help.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void merge(int originalArray[], int low, int high, int sizeOfOriginalArray){
    //    Step 4: Merge sorted halves into an auxiliary array
    int aux[sizeOfOriginalArray];
    int auxArrayIndex, left, right, mid;

    auxArrayIndex = low;
    mid = (low + high)/2;
    right = mid + 1;
    left = low;

    //    choose the smaller of the two values "pointed to" by left, right
    //    copy that value into auxArray[auxArrayIndex]
    //    increment either left or right as appropriate
    //    increment auxArrayIndex
    while ((left <= mid) && (right <= high)) {
        if (originalArray[left] <= originalArray[right]) {
            aux[auxArrayIndex] = originalArray[left];
            left++;
            auxArrayIndex++;
        }else{
            aux[auxArrayIndex] = originalArray[right];
            right++;
            auxArrayIndex++;
        }
    }

    //    here when one of the two sorted halves has "run out" of values, but
    //    there are still some in the other half; copy all the remaining values
    //    to auxArray
    //    Note: only 1 of the next 2 loops will actually execute
    while (left <= mid) {
        aux[auxArrayIndex] = originalArray[left];
        left++;
        auxArrayIndex++;
    }

    while (right <= high) {
        aux[auxArrayIndex] = originalArray[right];
        right++;
        auxArrayIndex++;
    }

    //    all values are in auxArray; copy them back into originalArray
    int index = low;
    while (index <= high) {
        originalArray[index] = aux[index];
        index++;
    }
}

void mergeSortArray(int originalArray[], int low, int high){
    int sizeOfOriginalArray = high + 1;
    //    base case
    if (low >= high) {
        return;
    }

    //    Step 1: Find the middle of the array (conceptually, divide it in half)
    int mid = (low + high)/2;

    //    Steps 2 and 3: Recursively sort the 2 halves of origianlArray and then merge those
    mergeSortArray(originalArray, low, mid);
    mergeSortArray(originalArray, mid + 1, high);
    merge(originalArray, low, high, sizeOfOriginalArray);
}

//O(n^2) solution without hash tables
//Basically using a sorted array, for each number in an array, you use two pointers, one starting from the number and one starting from the end of the array, check if the sum of the three elements pointed to by the pointers (and the current number) is >, < or == to the targetSum, and advance the pointers accordingly or return true if the targetSum is found.

bool is3SumPossible(int originalArray[], int targetSum, int sizeOfOriginalArray){
    int high = sizeOfOriginalArray - 1;
    mergeSortArray(originalArray, 0, high);

    int temp;

    for (int k = 0; k < sizeOfOriginalArray; k++) {
        for (int i = k, j = sizeOfOriginalArray-1; i <= j; ) {
            temp = originalArray[k] + originalArray[i] + originalArray[j];
            if (temp == targetSum) {
                return true;
            }else if (temp < targetSum){
                i++;
            }else if (temp > targetSum){
                j--;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {2, -5, 10, 9, 8, 7, 3};
    int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);
    int targetSum = 5;

    //3Sum possible?
    bool ans = is3SumPossible(arr, targetSum, size); //size of the array passed as a function parameter because the array itself is passed as a pointer. Hence, it is cummbersome to calculate the size of the array inside is3SumPossible()

    if (ans) {
        cout<<"Possible";
    }else{
        cout<<"Not possible";
    }

    return 0;
}
```